# GDB: recover control from blocked process

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I have the following problem: I want to recover control of gdb when a process enters a blocking situation i.e. a blocking function or a pooling loop.

Lets illustrate it with an example: I have process A which forks process B. B does its work and then gets stuck waiting for an event from A. I want to switch GDB to A so I can run it separately until the event generation. However, I can not recover control of GDB from B. Of course I can ctrl+C in B which generates a SIGINT signal, and then change to A, but when I go back to B, even if I handle pass SIGINT, B finishes.

```
Log:
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 0xb68feb40 (LWP 3177)]
0xb7fdeb0c in ?? ()
(gdb) handle SIGINT pass
SIGINT is used by the debugger.
Are you sure you want to change it? (y or n) y
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes   Yes Yes     Interrupt
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread 0xb7abcb40 (LWP 3178) exited]
[Thread 0xb68feb40 (LWP 3177) exited]
Couldn't get registers: No such process.

(gdb) info inferiors    
Num  Description       
* 2    <null>           
1    process 3168
```

Is there a way to recover control of GDB and switch process without killing it?

Comment: If A and B are separate processes, why not run gdb twice, once attached to A and once attached to B?

Comment: Is `$ detach` followed by `$ attach <pid of A>` what you are looking for?

Comment: @dohashi A creates B with a fork. B needs some configurations charged by A. I suppose I can try to execute B alone with the given configurations but this will require some work. I was expecting a "gdb in box" solution, but you have a point, thanks :)

Comment: If you know the PID of B you can attach to it after it has started.  Much like @Bhaskar suggests.